# Whats the difference between SUDO and Changing to root

Tags: command-line, root

If I issue a

```
sudo /bin/bash`  
[sudo] password for mark:
cmp -bl /dev/blah1 /dev/blah2
```

and using

```
sudo cmp -bl /dev/blah1 /dev/blah2
```

then logging in as root?

I don't see whats different, if issuing multiple command lines then `rooting` IMHO seems the logical option over typing sudo prefix to command lines.

I have seen `sudo -i` being used to log in to root, that used to work but the last week its issuing an error.

** **EDIT** **

I logged in as root, issued the command

```
mark@mark-zotac:~$ sudo cmp -bl /dev/sda "/media/mark/Seagate Expansion Drive/SSD/ssd.img"
[sudo] password for mark: 
mark@mark-zotac:~$
```

It ran, took about 30 minutes to run but produced `zero` as in `nothing` output. I am left with no indication of failure or success... So how do I know if the compare result was a success?

---

Comment: sudo lets you run with root priveleges and times out, root stays on as long as root is logged in. For security purposes, sudo is better. There's also sudo -i, which will log you in as root, but I've no idea of it times out or no

Comment: @Serg `sudo -l` doesn't login as anything (it is used to check privileges), so OP probably meant `-i`. Neither `-i` nor `-s` timeout (at least by default). `-i` is better as it resets some variables like `$HOME` which are left untouched by `-s`.

Comment: So doesn't closing the terminal kill processes like it stated when you close the terminal window? I much prefer logging in as root and then issuing and `exit` command or close the terminal.

Comment: @muru OP wanted to know difference, so that's what I was focusing on

Comment: @serg, where ever you have gone to as your comment isn't showing up, I possibly did mean `-i`, I am going through some strange issues with typing where I type a word and its all jumbled up, hence my query about rooting, mainly because I have typos and get fed up of typing, also another reason for logging in is to save my fingers which are beginning to early onset of arthritis :(

Comment: @MarkGiblin if the process is running and you close window, then yes, the process is killed. If you do Ctrl+Z, then execute `bg` the process will be ran in background independent. Or just do `sudo command &`

Comment: Not only moderators can mark questions as duplicate. Please use the meta site for this kind of discussion, and remove unrelated comments from the question. And the first  edit has nothing to do with su or sudo, is how the command `cmp` is supposed to work. `man cmp` will help - and reading about command exit status.

Comment: I think that the duplicates votes are clearly wrong (where is X involved here?) but also that the question are either a) two very different questions or b) really unclear.

Comment: If you can't post clear questions, don't get mad when people feel free to close as duplicate to absolute any question they prefer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following has been extracted directly from [the community wiki page on root sudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo).

`sudo` allows user to act as root without root login; it is more secure to use `sudo` instead of logging in as root.

### Advantages and Disadvantages

> #### Benefits of using `sudo`
>
> There are a number of benefits to Ubuntu leaving root logins disabled by default, including:
>
> 1. The installer has fewer questions to ask.
> 2. Users don't have to remember an extra password for occasional use
>      (i.e. the root password). If they did, they'd be likely to forget it (or record it unsafely, allowing anyone to easily crack into their system).
> 3. It avoids the "I can do anything" interactive login by default. You will be prompted for a password before any  major changes can happen, which should make you think about the consequences of what you are doing.
> 4. sudo adds a log entry of the command(s) run (in `/var/log/auth.log`). If you mess up, you can go back and see what commands were run.
> 5. On a server, every cracker trying to brute-force their way in will know it has an account named root and will try that first. What they don't know is what the usernames of your other users are. Since the root account password is locked, this attack becomes essentially meaningless, since there is no password to crack or guess in the first place.
> 6. Allows easy transfer for admin rights by adding and removing users from groups. When you use a single root password, the only way to de-authorize users is to change the root password.
> 7. `sudo` can be setup with a much more fine-grained security policy.
> 8. The root account password does not need to be shared with everybody who needs to perform some type of administrative task(s) on the system (see the previous bullet).
> 9. The authentication automatically expires after a short time (which
>      can be set to as little as desired or 0); so if you walk away from the terminal after running commands as root using `sudo`, you will not be leaving a root terminal open indefinitely.
>
> #### Downsides of using sudo
>
> Although for desktops the benefits of using sudo are great, there are possible issues which need to be noted:
>
> 1. Redirecting the output of commands run with sudo requires a
>      different approach. For instance consider `sudo ls > /root/somefile` will not work since it is the shell that sets up the redirections that tries to write to that file, not the command being run with root permission. You can use
>
>    ```
>    ls | sudo tee -a /root/somefile
>    ```
>
>    to append, or
>
>    ```
>    ls | sudo tee /root/somefile
>    ```
>
>    to overwrite contents. You could also pass the whole command to a shell process run under sudo to have the file written to with root permissions, such as
>
>    ```
>    sudo sh -c "ls > /root/somefile"
>    ```
> 2. In a lot of office environments the ONLY local user on a system is root. All other users are imported using NSS techniques such as nss-ldap. To setup a workstation, or fix it, in the case of a network failure where `nss-ldap` is broken, root is required. This tends to leave the system unusable unless cracked. An extra local user, or an enabled root password is needed here. The local user account should have its $HOME on a local disk, *not* on NFS (or any other networked filesystem), and a `.profile` / `.bashrc` that doesn't reference any files on NFS mounts. This is usually the case for root, but if adding a non-root rescue account, you will have to take these precautions manually. However the advantage of using a local user with `sudo` is that commands can be easily tracked, as mentioned in the benefits above.
>
> ### Misconceptions about root login
>
> 1. Isn't `sudo` less secure than `su`?
>
>    The basic security model is the same, and therefore these two
>      systems share their primary weaknesses. Any user who uses `su` or `sudo` must be considered to be a privileged user. If that user's account is compromised by an attacker, the attacker can also gain root privileges the next time the user does so. The user account is the weak link in this chain, and so must be protected with the same care as root.
>
>    On a more esoteric level, `sudo` provides some features which encourage different work habits, which can positively impact the security of the system. `sudo` is commonly used to execute only a single command, while `su` is generally used to open a shell and execute multiple commands. The `sudo` approach reduces the likelihood of a root shell being left open indefinitely, and encourages the user to minimize their use of root privileges.
> 2. I won't be able to enter single-user mode!
>
>    The sulogin program in Ubuntu is patched to handle the default case of a locked root  password.
> 3. I can get a root shell from the console without entering a password!
>
>    You have to enter your password.
>
>    Console users have access to the boot loader, and can gain administrative privileges in various ways during the boot process. For example, by specifying an alternate init(8) program. Linux systems are not typically configured to be secure at the console, and additional steps (for example, setting a root password, a boot loader password and a BIOS password) are necessary in order to make them so. Note that console users usually have physical access to the machine and so can manipulate it in other ways as well.
>
> #### Special notes on sudo and shells
>
> None of the methods below are suggested or supported by the designers of Ubuntu.
>
> Please do not suggest this to others unless you personally are available 24/7 to support the user if they have issues as a result of running a shell as root.
>
> To start a root shell (i.e. a command window where you can run root commands), starting root's environment and login scripts, use:
>
> - `sudo -i`     (similar to `sudo su -` , gives you roots environment configuration)
>
> To start a root shell, but keep the current shell's environment, use:
>
> - `sudo -s`     (similar to `sudo su`)
>
> Here's a brief overview of some of the differences between `su`, `su -`, and `sudo -{i,s}`
>
> ```
>                 HOME=/root      uses root's PATH     env vars
> sudo -i         Y               Y[2]                 N
> sudo -s         N               Y[2]                 Y
> sudo bash       N               Y[2]                 Y
> sudo su         Y               N[1]                 Y
>
> [1] PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games  (probably set by /etc/environment)
>
> [2] PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
> ```

Comment: I disagree with the "basic security model is the same" line, which is absolute BS. `sudo` has all sorts of checks in place, it's just not applied to the default user. `su` doesn't care what you do.

Comment: @ubuntu99 - perhaps better to quote the relevant sections from the community wiki rather than wholesale copy-paste.  Thus I've converted this to CW since it is not really your work but the effort of the community.

Comment: Don't forget another downside of sudo is that it drops the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and similars, so you will have to pass them with the call of sudo to be able to link your libraries

Answer (score 5):

The question has nothing related to difference between `sudo` and `su`.

The man page of `cmp` reads:

> The cmp utility compares two files of any type and writes the results
>   to the standard output. By default, cmp is silent if the files are the
>   same; if they differ, the byte and line number at which the first
>   difference occurred is reported.

So no output means that the two files are the same.