# Why doesn't the admin always run an admin terminal?

Tags: security

If I'm the admin, is there a benefit to using sudo in front of every command that requires it instead of just turning on root access with sudo -i and not worrying about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate, the answer here explains it well :  [http://askubuntu.com/questions/592825/whats-the-difference-between-sudo-and-changing-to-root](http://askubuntu.com/questions/592825/whats-the-difference-between-sudo-and-changing-to-root)